# Can't two way bind object which is inside of an object

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I'm trying to two way bind in a datagrid one class.

The strucure of class is like this:

```
class Company : BaseProps
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public Employee Employee { get; set; }

    public List<WorkTime> WorkTimes { get; set; }
}
```

And Employee looks like this:

```
class Technique : BaseProps
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now im trying to bind this to my datagrid

```
<DataGrid Name="CompanyGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="Auto" Margin="10,10,0,33.6" Width="Auto" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CompanyName}" Header="Kompānijas nosaukums"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Employee.Name}" Header="Vadītāja vārds"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Employee.Surname}" Header="Vadītāja uzvārds"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

When I enter CompanyName, nothing happens. When I try to enter Employee.Name or Surname 
I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Two-way binding requires Path or XPath.'

Comment: Do the `Name` and `Surname` properties of the `Employee` class have public setters?

Answer (score -1):

Seems like adding Mode=TwoWay fixes the error...

EDIT: And i like how yall be down voting a simple question and answer. :)